# What checks were done on Korbanos for internal disqualifications?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, korban

An animal that is schechted has to be checked for certain potential internal damages which would render it unfit for eating. I have been told that an animal which is "treif" for the sake of eating would be similarly disqualified as a korban.

I assume (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that the process of checking to make sure an animal is acceptable takes some time. But the process of a korban doesn't seem to have any time built in for the checking -- the text speaks of sprinkling blood etc, not of "first we have to inspect the animal."

My local expert also said that the time is reduced today because even though there are over 20 other potential organ-based disqualifiers, we only check the lungs. But I assume that even that takes time. And that reduction is a result of modern farming and animal care.

So in ancient days, what kind of checks were done on the internal organs of an animal and how did that play into the chronological process of performing all the aspects of a sacrifice ritual [side question would be, if an animal is found to be unacceptable because of a hidden, internal issue, who pays for a replacement]? Is there any discussion of how that process of checking will be reapplied in the future when we resume korbanot?

Comment: see chullin 11a